# Photoshop - How to choose a brush compatible with your selected tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, tools, brush-dynamics

At some point in Photoshop's development, brush settings became associated with specific tools. This is causing me frustration in my workflow. I will, for example, have the Smudge Tool selected, and then I go to look for a brush in the drop-down brush menu that matches the texture I want. But when I select the brush I want, the tool jumps back to the Brush Tool (as if pressing the B key).

I just want to smudge with a textured brush tip. How can I stop it from switching, or at least only display brushes that are going to work with my selected tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using the **Brush Presets panel** and use the **Brush Panel**.

Brush *presets* contain preconfigured, tool specific, settings....

The Brush panel contains only settings.

They are two separate panels....

[image]

Choosing a **Brush preset** will set the tool to that saved configuration.

Whereas changing *anything* in the *Brush* panel will merely alter the settings for the tool in use currently.

Comment: `Brush Presets` may not include tool info. I believe the OP wants to switch between _presets_ but encountered the new _feature_ of presets including the tool info.

Comment: Possibly @SergeyKritskiy I'm not one to use Presets.. so if there's a new feature there, I may have missed it.

Comment: Thank you! This is closest to what I was looking for - a way to change the Tip Shape of whatever brush I'm currently using. It's worth noting that the naming has been changed: **Brush** → **Brush Settings**, and **Brush Presets** → **Brushes** (To add to the confusion).

Answer (score 1):

If you click `Show Additional Preset Info` in the `Brushes` flyout menu you'll notice that some brush presets have icons in the top-right corner — those are presets with included tool settings (if I'm not mistaken this was added in CC2018 or CC2019):

[image]

Currently there's no way to ignore tool info of these presets to my knowledge (which is actually very useful in a lot of cases). I guess what you can do is create duplicate of the presets without the tool settings included:

1. Select a preset;
2. Click on `New Preset` button and make sure you have `Include Tool Settings` option deselected;

[image]

3. this will create a copy of the selected brush preset without the tool settings included;

[image]

As for why this change was made: I believe Adobe tries to consolidate Tool Presets and Brush Presets — that were living in two separate panels before — to one window. This makes sense to me (a lot of people had no idea about Tool Presets). But the change was made in quite a crude way, yes.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail. It's good to know how to do this, especially if making custom brushes. And if I ever decide I want to make a new version of each one of my brushes, in order to un-**** what Adobe has done here, I will. :-) But chances are, I will be too lazy to, and just change the Tip Shape each time after selecting my brush instead.